# Implication of retractions existing for a map

Tags: category-theory

**Definition**

1. Let $f$ be a map $A \to B$. Retraction for map $f$ is a map $r$ such that $r \circ f = I_{A}$.
2. Let $f$ be a map $A \to B$, $h$ a map from $A \to C$. Then the problem of finding a map $g$ $B \to C$ such that $g \circ f = h$ is called a determination problem.
3. Let $f$ be map $A \to B$, $h$ a map $C \to B$. Then the problem of finding a map $g$ $C \to A$ such that $f \circ g = h$ is called a choice problem.

**Background**
I have started reading category theory by William Lawvere. There is a theorem in it which states if map $f$ $A \to B$ has a retraction $r$, then we can always find a solution to the determination problem, ie. we can find the concerned map $g$ ( as shown below ).

[image]

**My question**
 
The theorem does not tell if there exists a retraction $r$ for map $A \to B$ then the choice problem also has a solution. That is we can find the concerned map $g$ ( as shown below ).
[image]
Am I missing something or am I wrong about the result the theorem does not tell. Is there a reason why the author links solution of retraction problem to a determination problem ( and not to a choice problem ) ?

Comment: In order to solve the choice problem, you need to have a section for $f$ instead of a retraction. It's exactly the same theorem with the arrows reversed. If having a retraction was enough to solve the choice problem, it would mean that having a section would also be sufficient to solve the determination problem, which is not part of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you haven't solved the choice problem: you have no grounds to conclude
$$f\gamma h = h$$
In fact, by considering the particular case of $h = 1_B$, you have
$$f \gamma 1_B = 1_B$$
if and only if $\gamma = f^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes I observed that. But if we apply map $r$ on both sides of the same maps $f \circ g = h$ we get $g = r \circ h$. What am I doing wrong ? It seems paradoxical to me :)

Comment: @sashas: What you are doing wrong is assuming the $g$ you constructed satisfies the equation $f \circ g = h$.

Comment: But $g$ is like an unknown which I have to find and which satisfies $f \circ g = h$. What is wrong in solving for $g$, by applying $r$ on both sides. I am really sorry but I am unable to understand.

Comment: @sashas: Because you've made the usual elementary algebra mistake of doing the converse of what you are actually trying to do: your backwards work shows "If a solution for $g$ exists, then $g = r \circ h$", but you never did the forwards work "$r \circ h$ is a solution for $g$" (or, in the light of the backwards work, in this case it would be enough even just to prove "A solution for $g$ exists")

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f: A→B$ and f has a retraction $r$. And further suppose that $h:C→B$ is given. Problem is to find $g$ such that $f∘g=h$ (1)
Now, take $$g=r∘h$$.
Substituting in (1),
$$f∘(r∘h)=h$$
Solving left hand side,
Using associative identity,
$$(f∘r)∘h=1_B∘h$$

This is the step where you assumed that equality always holds, and you saw that $1_B∘h=h$. But recognize in the definition of retraction, that $r$ is retraction of $f$ if $r∘f=1_A$. Counter Example: Suppose that if $r$ is not inverse of $f$, then $f∘r=1_B$ is not true and $r$ is still a retraction. (Because if $f∘r=1_B$ is true then r is inverse of f, which will contradict our assumption).